# grouping by rows in python

Tags: python, consolidation

I have a huge dump of records in a file.

```
Filename     Col1   Col2   Col3  Col4
SE01_inf     name    []     NA    []
SE01_loc      NA    loc     NA    []
SE01_id       NA     []    123    []
SE01_1_inf   name1   []     NA    []
SE01_1_loc    NA     loc    NA    []
```

I want a consolidated output like below

```
Filename     Col1   Col2   Col3  Col4
SE01         name   loc    123    []
SE01_1       name1  loc     NA    []
```

I do not want to do it in excel as the data is huge and excel gets stuck the moment I write a function. Can I achieve this using python, I am not very clear on how to start.

Comment: In what format is your data stored?

Comment: What have you tried?  You will get much better answers here you have code, rather than a list of (badly defined) requirements.

Comment: @bpmason - data is a python list

Comment: I meant, what is the format of the input file that you are attempting to parse?

Comment: Does xxx_loc always store data for column 2, _id always for column 3 and _inf always for column 1. Is it the way how it is organised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How huge is the data? If memory isn't a problem and you have the data in a list this works for you example input:

```
input = [['SE01_inf', 'name', [], 'NA', []],\
         ['SE01_loc', 'NA', 'loc', 'NA', []],\
         ['SE01_id', 'NA', [], '123', []],\
         ['SE01_1_inf', 'name1', [], 'NA', []],\
         ['SE01_1_loc', 'NA', 'loc', 'NA', []]]

output = {}
for row in input:
    id = row[0][:row[0].rfind('_')]
    if id not in output:
        output[id] = [id] + row[1:]
    else:
        output[id] = [new if old in ('NA', []) else old for new, old in zip(row, output[id])]

print output.values()
```

Produces the output:

```
[['SE01', 'name', 'loc', '123', []], ['SE01_1', 'name1', 'loc', 'NA', []]]
```

Answer (score 1):

@Akinakes 's answer is excellent. Here are some tips in another way:

If you have

```
input = [['name', '[]', 'NA', '[]'],\
     ['NA', 'loc', 'NA', '[]'],\
     ['NA', '[]', '123', '[]']]
```

you can try

```
def fil(l):
    tl = filter(lambda x:x not in ('NA','[]'), l)
    if len(tl) == 0:
        tl = [l[-1]]
    t = str(*tl)
    return t

output = map(fil, zip(*input))
```

the output will be:

```
['name', 'loc', '123', '[]']
```